# Rating average from Mysql db using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Everyone,

I am working an rating average value for every review and 4 fields (price,quality,support and delivery) of rating. From following function return wrong average value. It should return 2 but returning 1.

```
function review_rating_average($pid,$cid,$rid) {
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT rate_price, rate_quality, rate_support, rate_delivery FROM reviews WHERE (product_id = $pid and client_id = $cid and review_id = $rid)");

    $array = array();
    foreach($query as $row) {
        $array[1] = 2;
        $array[2] = 1;
        $array[3] = 4;
        $array[4] = 3;
    }
    $result = implode(", ", $array);

    $stars = array($result);    
    foreach ($stars as $star) {
        $rating[] = $star;
    }

    $average = array_sum($rating) / count($rating);
    return $average;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is... all kinds of wrong.

I mean aside from not actually using `$query` (or `$row`), I'll assume that's just for testing, just look at the rest of it...

```
// $array = [ , 2,1,4,3];
$result = implode(", ", $array);
// $result = "2, 1, 4, 3";

$stars = array($result);    
// $stars = ["2, 1, 4, 3"];
foreach ($stars as $star) {
    $rating[] = $star;
}
// $rating = ["2, 1, 4, 3"]; // foreach loop is a big no-op...

$average = array_sum($rating) / count($rating);
// $average = 2 (due to casting string to number) / 1 = 2
return $average;
```

It's a mess, none of it does what you mean for it to do.

Just do this:

- Pass in the MySQLi connection so you can actually use it
- `fetch_row` on your `$query` result
- `return array_sum($row) / count($row);`

You don't even need to transform anything, your data from the database is already in perfect form to just be averaged!

Comment: I am not good with array things can please explain with some code.

Comment: I made it as now less code and it works, 
`$arrays = $query;
 foreach ($arrays as $array){
  $rating[0] = $array['rating_price'];
  $rating[1] = $array['rating_quality'];
  $rating[2] = $array['rating_support'];
  $rating[3] = $array['rating_delivery'];
 }
 $average = ceil( array_sum($rating) / count($rating) );
 return $average;`

Comment: Uhh... sure. Or you could just do `$average = array_sum($query[0]) / count($query[0]);`...